# Why isn't "safely disposing" written as "safe disposing" instead?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

> The cost of safely disposing of the toxic chemicals is approximately five times what the company paid to purchase them.

The *-ing* and *of* seem indicate that "disposing" is a noun, and since "safely" is modifying "disposing" then shouldn't we use the adjective "safe" rather than the adverb "safely"?

Comment: 'Dispose' is the root of the verb which is being modified by the adverb 'safely'.

Comment: Not sure where you're getting the idea "disposing" is a noun. dispose is a verb that is followed by "of" and an object. safely adverbially modifies the verb.

Comment: Note that *dispose of sb/sth* is a phrasal verb.

Comment: As a side note, if you want a noun form of 'dispose', try 'disposal'.

Answer (score 1):

The *-ing* indicates that "disposing" is a [present participle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Participle), not a noun. The "of" indicates that it is *used* as a noun in the greater context of the sentence. Within its own phrase, it is still being used as a verb, though — and can, as such, be modified by an adverb.

This construction is grammatical, idiomatic, and *extremely* common in English. The term for this is [*gerund*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerund):

> In Latin and English grammar, the gerund is a non-finite verb form that can function as a noun. [...]
>
> In English, the gerund is one of the uses of the form of the verb ending in *-ing*. [...]
>
> **A gerund behaves as a verb within a clause (so that it may be modified by an adverb or have an object); but the resulting clause as a whole** (sometimes consisting of only one word, the gerund itself) **functions as a noun within the larger sentence.**

Emphasis added. As you can see, your example sentence is a perfect example of just that.

Answer (score -3):

*Safe disposal* is not the same thing as *safely disposing*.

In a way, the *safely* relates to the (avoiding any) effect on whoever is doing the disposal. **You** are safe when you *safely dispose* of something.

On the other hand, adjective in *safe disposal* is disposing of something in such a way as not to cause hazardous effects to the environment (**the others!**).

However, *safe disposal* can also be used in the first-mentioned sense, but not *vice versa*. i.e., *safely disposing* cannot mean an environment-friendly way of doing it.

Comment: Isn't "safely" an adverb?

Comment: Oh yes, the POS should have been in the next para. Edited.

Comment: This is ***not*** the way the [Australian EPA](http://www.epa.nsw.gov.au/waste/asbestos/) uses the term *"safely disposing"*. It's not the way I would understand it either. Can you give any references that show this is a real distinction?

Comment: @PeterShor The **First two sentences** of the reference you cited show the distinction. Please take your time.